# Background image size not working on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, background, responsive-design, shopify

So everything is working fine on the browsers but when it comes to the mobile the background is zoomed in. I'm using the cover keyword in order to get the background image stretched out.

```
background-image: url({{ settings.site_bg_image | asset_url }});
background-position: {{ settings.bg_image_y_position }} {{ settings.bg_image_x_position }};
background-repeat: {{ settings.bg_image_repeat }};
background-attachment: {{ settings.bg_image_attachment }};
background-size: cover;
```

The settings for position in the backend is set to top center

tiling: tile vertically

Scrolling: stays fixed

Here is a link to check out what is going on
http://www.iconiccustomguitars.com

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
background: url(bg.png);
```

to

```
background-image: url(bg.png);
```

Also add quotes to it to make it like this:

```
background-image: url("bg.png");
```

Comment: Well this is what it is set to 

     background-image: url({{ settings.site_bg_image | asset_url }});

Comment: body { background-image: url({{'background.jpg' | asset_url }});} center top no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;}

Comment: That did not work. It's something to do with the mobile that is not set right

Comment: Maybe try something like this.

    @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .body {
    background: #FFFFFF url("bg.png");
    }
    }

Comment: That did not work either. Here is all the code in the stylesheet.css though

http://pastebin.com/P3a6uVzt

Answer (score 0):

Your image dimensions are the issue, but I may have a solution for you.  I would recommend clipping the image in photoshop to cut out some of the middle space for mobile.

But try this

```
background-size:contain;
```

Repeats the image on the y axis, retaining aspect ratio

OR

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Stretches the image to the viewport;